# Retorno de JSON array

Tags: java, android, json

O meu JSON retorna mais de um número. Como fazer pra receber todos e não um só?

Gostaria de setar o retorno em um `TextView`. Como fazer ele retornar todos os valores e não só o primeiro?

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json.getString("resource"));
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

    mId_user = jsonObj.getString("id_user");
    mValorAnuncioVenda = jsonObj.getString("vl_anuncio");
    mNegativo = jsonObj.getString("vl_pago");
    mIdComp = jsonObj.getString("id_user_comp");

    if ((mIdComp != null) & (mNegativo != null)) {
        mPositivo = mNegativo;
        negativo.setText(mPositivo);

    }
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você quer. Você só postou um trecho de código que não termina. O que seria o valor de retorno? Esse código aí está dentro de algum método?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desta forma como está fazendo, inserindo o `setText()` dentro do laço de repetição, toda vez que o `for` der um ciclo completo, ele irá sobrepor o valor anterior, fazendo com que mostre apenas o ultimo valor.

Use [`StringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para armazenar os valores antes de usar o método `setText()`. Veja:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
```

Dentro de sua condição faça desta forma, concatenando os valores dentro do seu `for` usando o método `append`:

```
if ((mIdComp != null) & (mNegativo != null)) {
   mPositivo = mNegativo;
   // aqui você concatena os valores usando 
   str.append(mPositivo);
   str.append(" ");
}
```

Por fim, depois do laço, você usa o método `setText()` para mostrar os valores atribuídos dentro do `for` :

```
negativo.setText(str.toString());
```

Veja o **código completo**:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray array = null;
try {
    array = new JSONArray(json.getString("resource"));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

        mId_user = jsonObj.getString("id_user");
        mValorAnuncioVenda = jsonObj.getString("vl_anuncio");
        mNegativo = jsonObj.getString("vl_pago");
        mIdComp = jsonObj.getString("id_user_comp");

        if ((mIdComp != null) & (mNegativo != null)) {
            mPositivo = mNegativo;

            str.append(mPositivo);
            str.append(" ");
        }
    }
    negativo.setText(str.toString());

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado !